# Built-in methods to work with pandas.DataFrame rows in for-each manner

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with values that change over time. Every row has current value, maximum acceptable value, minimum acceptable value and label. I would like to find for each row's 'Value' first NEXT row with value that satisfies conditions determined by Max_Val and Min_Val columns (it means first row that satisfies: Min_Val < Value < Max_Val). Having this column I would like to get an access to Label of that row (Then I would create additional column with future labels and join it to this DataFrame). Is it possible to do it using some pandas (or any other library) built in methods in elegant way and avoid tons of loops?

```
import pandas as pd

max_next_values = [4.5, 2.6, 13.1, 9.6, 13.1]
min_next_values = [1.2, 3.3, 7.8, 4.4, 15.2]
values = [1.2, 2.3, 4.4, 8.9, 16.2]
labels = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Label': labels, 'Value': values, 'Max_Next_Val': max_next_values, 'Min_Next_Val': min_next_values})
```

Sample content of the dataframe:

```
       Label  Max_Next_Val  Min_Next_Val  Value
0     monday           4.5           1.2    1.2
1    tuesday           2.6           3.3    2.3
2  wednesday          13.1           7.8    4.4
3   thursday           9.6           4.4    8.9
4     friday          13.1          15.2   16.2
```

Desired output:

```
       Label  Max_Next_Val  Min_Next_Val  Value  Next_Label
0     monday           4.5           1.2    1.2  tuesday
1    tuesday           2.6           3.3    2.3  
2  wednesday          13.1           7.8    4.4  thursday
3   thursday           9.6           4.4    8.9
4     friday          13.1          15.2   16.2  NaN
```

Description:

0 - we are looking for row with: 4.5 > Value > 1.2. First row after 0-indexed row has value 2.3. We take it's label 'tuesday' and put in Next_Label column

1 - 2.6 > Value > 3.3 does not exist we put nothing.

2 - we are looking for row with: 13.1 > Value > 7.8. First row (with index 3) has value that satisfies this condition we put it's label 'thursday' into Next_Label

And so on...

Maybe there is a better option to store min and max values that would ease computations?

Comment: What is your expected output from this dataframe?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question and assumed the check was for each row separately. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48572606/edit) your question to add your desired output?

Comment: Also, what you described can be done with broadcasting but it can grow very quickly. What is the length of your DataFrame?

Comment: DataFrame would contain thousands of rows

Comment: you've got some errors in your min/max value columns

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do this:

```
d = df.apply(lambda x: ((x.Value > df.Min_Val) & (x.Value < df.Max_Val)), axis=1)

df['next'] = d[d].idxmax().map(df['Label'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
       Label  Max_Val  Min_Val  Value      next
0     monday      4.5      1.2    1.2   tuesday
1    tuesday      2.6      3.3    2.3       NaN
2  wednesday     13.1      7.8    4.4  thursday
3   thursday      9.6      4.4    8.9  thursday
4     friday     13.1     15.2   16.2       NaN
```

Comment: I think your answer is something I am looking for :) but for each row I would like to find Label only from first row that satisfies condition with index greater than this row's index. In case of row with index 3 there is only one possible row: row with index 4 but this row's Value does not satisfy min-max condition so for row with index 3 I would not put anything into 'next' column.